# Delete batch while it is open

Tags: windows, batch

I have a batch file that I want to run and after it runs code I want it to delete itself. Is it possible to do that? I've already tried using `del` and using `rd` to delete the directory where the file is located but that won't work either.

Comment: See [so] question [How to make .BAT file delete it self after completion?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20333152)

Comment: Does it have to be deleted right away or is deletion at reboot enough?

Comment: I would like it deleted right away but if it can be deleted after a reboot then that would work

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the answer referred to by David, this is not possible.

You cannot delete it because it is still open and therefore locked.

What you can do is have another job that deletes it once complete. This can be done by creating a one-off scheduled task from the running batch job. As David say's, see [How to make .BAT file delete it self after completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20333152) for more details.

Comment: You have misread my answer in multiple ways. 1) A batch script can delete itself normally, but it generates an error message after the file is deleted. 2) A batch script is ***not*** locked when it is run. 3) The clean solution need not use a scheduled task. I just used START /B

Comment: Seems you've deleted your answer anyway. Had you put the above into it, I wouldn't have misread it. Useful information that should be in its own answer.

Comment: Huh? I followed the link in your comment, and it takes me to my answer that describes how to have a running script cleanly delete itselft.